# Accessing Nativescript custom components

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

I am learning to build mobile apps using nativescript with angular2, and i created a custom component called booking. I am accessing this custom component from another component called main as shown in these files.

**booking.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Renderer, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild} from "@angular/core";
import { Page } from "ui/page";
import buttonModule = require("ui/button");
import tabViewModule = require("ui/tab-view");
import {StackLayout} from "ui/layouts/stack-layout"; 


import colorModule = require("color");
    var Color = colorModule.Color;

@Component({
  selector: "booking",
  templateUrl: "pages/booking/booking.html",
  styleUrls: ["pages/booking/booking-common.css", "pages/booking/booking.css"]
})

export class BookingComponent  implements OnInit   {
    oneWay = true;
    @ViewChild("oneWay") oneWayButton: ElementRef;
    @ViewChild("roundTrip") roundTripButton: ElementRef;
    @ViewChild("container") container: ElementRef;




  constructor(private page: Page, el: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer) {
        renderer.setElementClass(el.nativeElement, 'booking', true);
  }    

    ngOnInit() {
    this.toggle();
    this.hide();
    }   
    toggle(){
        this.oneWay = !this.oneWay;
        let oneWayButton = <buttonModule.Button>this.oneWayButton.nativeElement;
        let roundTripButton = <buttonModule.Button>this.roundTripButton.nativeElement;            
        if(this.oneWay){
             oneWayButton.backgroundColor = new Color('#fb9900');
             roundTripButton.backgroundColor = new Color('#052c5b');
        }
        else{
             oneWayButton.backgroundColor = new Color('#052c5b');
             roundTripButton.backgroundColor = new Color('#fb9900');            
        }
    }

    hide(){
        let container = <StackLayout>this.container.nativeElement;        
        container.set("visibility","collapsed");        
    } 
    show(){
        let container = <StackLayout>this.container.nativeElement;        
        container.set("visibility","visible");        
    } 

    getFromList(){
        alert("from list");
    }   
    getToList(){
        alert("to list")
    } 
}
```

**main.html**

```
  <DockLayout #dock width="100%" height="100%"  stretchLastChild="false"

      loaded="pageLoaded" 
  >
    <GridLayout columns="*,*,*,*" rows="auto, auto" width="100%" height="auto" class="tabs"  dock="bottom">
        <StackLayout  row = "0" rowSpan = "1" col = "0" colSpan="4" class="dockBorder"></StackLayout>
        <StackLayout (tap)="switchTab('booking')" row = "1" rowSpan = "1" col = "0" colSpan="1" class="tab">
           <StackLayout class="tabBar activeBar"></StackLayout> 
            <Image class = "tabIcon" src="~/images/bus.png" ></Image>
            <Label text="Booking" class="tabLabel activeLabel"></Label>         
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout (tap)="switchTab('hello')" row = "1" rowSpan = "1" col = "1" colSpan="1" class="tab">
           <StackLayout class="tabBar"></StackLayout> 
            <Image class = "tabIcon" src="~/images/bus.png" ></Image>
            <Label text="Booking" class="tabLabel"></Label>         
        </StackLayout>  
        <StackLayout row = "1" rowSpan = "1" col = "2" colSpan="1" class="tab">
           <StackLayout class="tabBar"></StackLayout> 
            <Image class = "tabIcon" src="~/images/bus.png" ></Image>
            <Label text="Booking" class="tabLabel"></Label>         
        </StackLayout>  
        <StackLayout row = "1" rowSpan = "1" col = "3" colSpan="1" class="tab">
           <StackLayout class="tabBar"></StackLayout> 
            <Image class = "tabIcon" src="~/images/bus.png" ></Image>
            <Label text="Booking" class="tabLabel"></Label>         
        </StackLayout>                        
    </GridLayout>
    <StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
    <hello id="hello" #hello></hello>
    <booking #booking></booking>

  </DockLayout>
```

**main.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild} from "@angular/core";
import { Page } from "ui/page";
import {StackLayout} from "ui/layouts/stack-layout"; 
import colorModule = require("color");
import {BookingComponent} from "../booking/booking.component"
import {Hello} from "../hello/hello.component"
import {DockLayout} from  "ui/layouts/dock-layout"; 
var Color = colorModule.Color;   
@Component({
  selector: "main-dock",
  templateUrl: "pages/main/main.html",
  styleUrls: ["pages/main/main-common.css", "pages/main/main.css"],
})    
export class MainComponent implements OnInit{
  @ViewChild("booking") booking: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("hello") hello: ElementRef;
  active = this.booking;
  constructor(private page: Page) {
  }     
  ngOnInit() {
    this.page.actionBarHidden = true;
    this.switchTab("booking");    
  }

  switchTab(tab){
    let b = <BookingComponent>this.booking.nativeElement;
    let h = <Hello>this.hello.nativeElement;  
    if(tab ==="booking" && this.active != this.booking){          
         h.hide();
         b.show();                  
    }
    else{         
         b.hide();
         h.show();          
    }
  }
}
```

everything is working fine but the problem is that when using nativeElement with the custom components it returns undefined; therefore i cant use the custom components methods. can someone show me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem too and I don't know it's bug or not, but I found solution for that.
use (loaded) event like this:

```
   <booking #booking (loaded) =onLoaded(booking)></booking>

   onLoaded(booking){
          //booking is equal to this.booking.nativeElement
          //you can use it as you like
   }
```

related Issue:
     https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/406

UPDATE:
     I think your problem is because you called   `this.switchTab("booking");` in `ngOnInit` use it in `ngAfterViewInit` but it might have some problems again (see the above link) the solution I mentioned above is the best solution I found.

Comment: That works great! thank you. I was just wondering does the this.booking.nativeElement doesnt work with custom components? also should I use this way only with custom components or should i generalize and not use nativeElement at all?

Comment: the problem is in ngAfterViewInit when u use booking.nativeElement.android property the android is not available sometimes (like when you routing in to that component) but if you use timeout then .android will be available.so you can use nativeElement but you should test if it's really works or you should use timeout and ... .I think it's a bug.